# mongodb $nin operator doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

I am fiddling a bit with mongodb.

I have 2 collections with documents sharing same ids and I want to get all documents ids from colB not in colA.
Ids are simple integers

First I fetch all IDs from colA in an array and then use it with the $nin operator in a second query.
But the $nin operator returns no data.

Is the array provided to the $nin operator too large? The query returns no error.

(On a production environment I would probably check the consistency in an other way)

Take a look at my troubleshoot mongoshell script.

Output

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5
connecting to: test
MATCHES
2032
MATCHES DETAILS
2004
MATCHES DETAILS not found using manual check
28
MATCHES DETAILS not found using find $nin
0
MATCHES DETAILS found using find $in
2004
```

Script

```js
var rito = new Mongo("localhost").getDB("riotData");
var allMatchesIds = rito.matches.find({}, {_id: true}).map(a => a._id );

var allMatchesDetailIds = rito.matchDetail.find({}, {_id: true}).map(a => a._id );

var matchesNotFound = [];
for (var i = 0; i < allMatchesIds.length ; i++ ) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < allMatchesDetailIds.length ; j++ ) {
        if(allMatchesIds[i] === allMatchesDetailIds[j])
            found = true;
    }
    if(!found)
        matchesNotFound.push(allMatchesIds[i])
}

var matchesNotFoundMongo = rito.matchDetail.find({_id: {$nin: allMatchesIds}},{_id: true}).count();
var matchesFound = rito.matchDetail.find({_id: {$in: allMatchesIds}},{_id: true}).count();

print("MATCHES");
printjson(allMatchesIds.length);
print("MATCHES DETAILS");
printjson(allMatchesDetailIds.length);
print("MATCHES DETAILS not found using manual check");
printjson(matchesNotFound.length);

print("MATCHES DETAILS not found using find $nin");
printjson(matchesNotFoundMongo);
print("MATCHES DETAILS found using find $in");

printjson(matchesFound);
```

Comment: Is the matched id really the same data type as the original id?

Comment: yes and look at my test with the the $in operator. It returns the right number of documents (2004 out of 2032)